# How to capture the value of a variable from jquery function using VBA?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, excel, web-crawler

I want to capture the value of a variable from a JQuery function which is call implicitly by click on botton of a web page.

```
function onclick()
{
DoPreview()
}
 '************
  function DoPreview() 
  {
        var url = "";
        var draftView = false;
        var newEmaeaApconfig = false;

        if ($("input[name$=rbtnlstGridCustDraft]:visible:checked").val() == 'Customer View')
            draftView = false;
        else {

            draftView = true;
        }

        if ($("input[name$=rbtnlstforJPQ2C]:visible:checked").val() == 'New EMEA/AP Config')
            newEmaeaApconfig = true;
        else {

            newEmaeaApconfig = false;
        }

        var role = $('[id$=ddlGridRolesPrvw]:visible').val();
        var accessGrp = $('[id$=ddlGridUAG]:visible').val();

        var params = "{ 'isDraftView': '" + draftView + "', 'isNewEmeaApConfig': '" + newEmaeaApconfig + "', 'accessGrpId': '" + accessGrp + "', 'roleId': '" + role + "' }";

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'Home.aspx/GetPagePreviewUrl',
            type: "POST",
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                url = data.d;

                window.open(url, '_blank');

                //$("div[id$=pgprwGridModalpnl]:first").dialog("close");

                $("div[id$=pgprwGridModalpnl]:visible").remove();
                $("[id$=pgprwGridModalpnl]:visible").dialog("close");

                return false;
            }

        });


    }
```

Here i want to capture the value of "url" using VBA.
when i perform a click event on button then DoPreview() is calling implicitly and navigating a url and getting redirect immediately thus i could not able to capture it by "LocationUrl"
thanks in advance.